# facebook logout session not being destroyed

Tags: jquery

In my app when any user try to logout from facebook it will logout but when we change url or remove logout link from url the user will be login again .... I think its an issue of facebook session but I cant destroy it.....

here is my code for log out

```
  FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
  statusChangeCallback(response);
  if (response.status === 'connected') 
  {

  console.log(response.authResponse.accessToken);
  }

  <?php if ($this->input->get('l')=="logout") {?>
  FB.logout();

     $facebook->destroySession();       
     //$this->session->session_destroy();

 <?php  }  ?>

});
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: did you try to remove php and do that logic with JS only?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to move

```
  <?php if ($this->input->get('l')=="logout") {?>
  FB.logout();
```

up more in your code.. before FB.getLoginStatus

EDIT:

remove php from that page and do not use it at all.. do all the logic in javascript, for instance, when user clicks on button do logout, for example:

```
$('button').on( 'click', function(e){
  FB.logout();
});
```

Comment: remove php completely!